# Remove hover style from every button in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add this code to every button in my C# Project:

```
button1.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = button1.BackColor;
button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = button1.BackColor;
button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

I've tried this code in the Form_Load event but the var b stays null:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            Button b = c as Button;
            if (b != null)
            {
                b.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = b.BackColor;
                b.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = b.BackColor;
                b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            }
        }
```

What can i do?

Comment: Are you sure that you have buttons on your form? Or are they maybe on another on the form? More information on the controls on your form would be helpful.

Comment: Is this a wpf question?

Comment: @JoePhillips I don't think you can access WPF controls like that, so I assumed it is about WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just assume this is about WinForms.

As your code seems to work when the buttons are directly on the form, they probably are on another control (a container) on the form. You could now search for container and check wether they contain a button, however this gets awkward when they have container as well. Therefore I'd suggest to use recursion:

```
private List<Control> GetAllControls(Control parent)
{
    List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
    controls.AddRange(parent.Controls.Cast<Control>()); //add all controls directly being on the current control
    controls.AddRange(parent.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany(GetAllControls)); //add all children from each control
    return controls;
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
foreach (Control c in GetAllControls(this))
{
    Button b = c as Button;
    if (b != null)
    {
        b.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = b.BackColor;
        b.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = b.BackColor;
        b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    }
}
```

You can read more about recursion [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/recursion).